# Where to get old LineageOS ROMs?

Tags: custom-roms, lineageos

I have a few old devices which I want to put on LineageOS. This time it's about a **Samsung Galaxy S4 mini** (GT-I9195, serranoltexx). But the [official LineageOS website shows them as not supported anymore](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/serranoltexx/install).

You basically are required to build the ROM for yourself, but this is beyond my knowledge and commitment.

I already have flashed successfully exactly such a device with LineageOS in the past, but do not have the ZIP around anymore.

**Why does LineageOS not keep the latest versions of their ROM's around for download? Where to get a trustworthy copy?**

Note: The same happened with cyanogenmod earlier. The did not store older ROM's too.

Note2: [These devices were still on sale on recycling shops recently](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:PhMjUJx3xlMJ:https://www.benno-shop.ch/peripherie/smartphone/samsung/2692/samsung-galaxy-s4-mini-8gb-android-4%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ch&client=firefox-b-d).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the question (getting old builds) directly - there are people who foresaw the need and stashed some of the builds elsewhere: [1](https://files.moskvich.xyz/LineageOS), [2](https://archive.org/download/LINEAGEOS_EXTRAS_11272018).

As for the reason to it, it's right in their [FAQ](https://wiki.lineageos.org/faq.html#where-can-i-find-the-last-build-for-xxx-device-before-support-was-droppedits-lineageos-version-was-deprecated). The main reason would be to save bandwidth/storage, since the project is a non-profit.

Comment: Thanks for this insightful answer. I choose this one over the first, because it also addresses the why.

Comment: It's sad, but understandable, that they deprecate old builds. In face, I only try alternative ROM's on older phones I plan to recycle for my family use.

Comment: Using unofficial builds on XDA isn't necessarily a bad choice - in fact I myself am an advocate of doing so. The Android version / security patch will be more updated, and most devs are trusted and communicate with users through the forum freely. If there's a relatively bugless unofficial build for your device, I say use that instead. As you can see my answer is more to directly answer your original question :)

Comment: Removing old builds for saving space is reasonable but at least they should have recorded the SHA256 hashes on the removed builds to make it possible for people to search for them.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [XDA-Developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4-mini/orig-development/rom-lineageos-16-0-s4-mini-t3833063) to download Lineage OS for your device. But the ROMs posted are not official versions and might not always work as smoothly as the official. The version posted on the link is Lineage OS 16.

Comment: Thanks. They seem to have even recent builds. I'll try them out tonight!

Comment: Although I was eventually not able to flash (because of internal storage failure on the phone) these ROM's seem to be the ones I was looking for.