# How safe is it to build and flash LineageOS myself?

Tags: rom-flashing, lineageos

I was planning to flash LineageOS on my Asus Zenfone 2 Laser, but I recently found out it is **no longer supported on my phone**. However, [this guide](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/Z00L) explains how to build then flash the ROM on my device (and possibly root it), and I truly want to go down this path.

What is unclear to me a this point is whether it is "safe" to do so. More specifically:

- Will I be getting security updates ?
- Will it be safe to use banking apps with the custom ROM ?
- What can happen if I lose/someone steals my phone ?
- Should I stick with my bloated stock ROM ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Does your bloated stock ROM get regular security updates? Is it safe to use banking apps on it? I would argue that this can only be determined per device, since some devices lose support from their manufacturers quicker than others due to popularity in sales.

Comment: @LucasRamage Perhaps you're right. On mine, the "About" section indicates "Android security patch level : feb 5 2018" (or something like that, because it's in French). Does this look reasonably recent to you?

Comment: That's better than many for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Will I be getting security updates ?

LOS team will keep merging in Android-side security patches, so each time you sync and build you get the latest they've merged, but kernel-side ones are up to you.

- Will it be safe to use banking apps with the custom ROM ?

Root is optional on LOS - if you don't opt into that, the risk is low.

- What can happen if I lose/someone steals my phone ?

With encrypted data and a good enough lockscreen passcode, your data will be secure.

- Should I stick with my bloated stock ROM ?

Why did you ask this question in the first place? ;)

Comment: BTW, if you just want to get any LineageOS build or even any custom ROM, check [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213272/where-to-get-old-lineageos-roms/213297#213297) for older LOS builds, and [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/zenfone-2-laser) for more stuff.

Comment: I think it should be noted that to receive the LOS patches, OP will have to update their source, rebuild and flash the updated system. They won't be available OTA

Comment: @AndyYan Thank you for your quick response !
Supposing that I root while flashing, do I have to be as careful as with any other rooted phone ? (I'm thinking of using automation for advanced customization)

Comment: @Namnodorel Done.

Comment: @mEEGal It's rooted, no different. Handle carefully.