# installing lineageOS on Huawei VNS-L31

Tags: huawei, operating-system

I want to install LineageOS on my phone, Huawei VNS-L31 but I'm afraid that it couldn't be supported especially after I couldn't find it on lineage website but found some websites that claim it could be supported, I'd appreciate any help on how to install it, if possible.

Also, I'd appreciate any recommended OS that could work on Huawei VNS-L31 outside Google's and Apple's worlds.

Thank you.

Comment: I think it was in the beginning of 2019 Lineage OS dropped support for a large number of old devices. Also the downloads were removed. If there was an official Lineage OS  version for your device it is now gone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to get old LineageOS ROMs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213272/where-to-get-old-lineageos-roms)