# Custom rom can I trust? Can I install pure android instead?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, custom-roms, lineageos, operating-system

I have a "galaxy tab E" device, it is old in years, but it is quite new because I don't use it very often.
The problem is, it has android 4.4.4.
I notice it has a custom rom to install android 7.1.2 Nougat (see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmRtueImtlw) It is a rom made by lineage.
First question, can I trust this rom?

Is there a way to install pure android (7.1.2) from google instead? If I download android from google and install it using odin will it work?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to get old LineageOS ROMs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213272/where-to-get-old-lineageos-roms)

Comment: The main question is it an original LineageOS ROM (built and released by LineageOS) or is it a LineageOS based custom ROM. The latter can contain any modification and thus is less trustable than an original build. An original LineageOS ROM should contain a cryptographic signature by LineageOS and therefore it can be verified.

Comment: "*Is there a way to install pure android (7.1.2) from google instead?*" if by "Google", it's "Google, the company", no, because Google doesn't provide ROM for non-Google devices, just like other manufacturers. If it's "Google, the search engine", plausibly, since ROMs on popular forum like XDA usually get some review and feedback from their users directly on there.

Comment: In the rom zip file it is named as lineage-14.1-20180419-UNOFFICIAL-gtel3g, so, yeah, I think it is not a original lineage rom.