# How to fix completely non-functioning Gionee S10C Android phone?

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, fastboot, 7.0-nougat, android-10

My phone is Gionee S10C and I have Android 7.1.1 installed on it.

I was going to upgrade the Android version to 10, but Gionee no longer provides OS updates(Not sure whether the company even exists now), so I tried to flash Lineage OS 17.x from [this site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/andyyan-gsi/files/lineage-17.x/).

I connected the phone via USB cable, opens up command prompt on Android platforms folder and run `adb reboot-bootloader` to enter the bootloader screen of the phone.

And then I tried to run `fastboot flash -w system lineage-17.x.x.img`.

After rebooting, my phone is not longer running, but completely bricked. It keeps stuck in the Gionee logo screen and keeps rebooting when entering the `Recovery screen`.

I tried factory reset, but that didn't work out.

FYI, I forgot to run `fastboot oem unlock`.

The worst case is that I can't find the device on Windows, which means `adb devices` returns nothing even the phone is plugged in.(`fastboot devices` in the `bootloader screen` shows the device)

So now I'm going to re-install the original Android OS on the phone, so that I can use it, but no method works because of adb disconnecting.

I tried the steps from this [site](https://romforandroid.com/download-gionee-s10c-stock-firmware-rom-flash-file/) using various Flash Tools, but no tool can find the connected phone.

All I can do now is to use `fastboot`.

(I was going to use `fastboot flash` to overwrite the `system` partition with the one from the original ROM, but there are too many images for the system like `system1.img`, `system2.img`, .... - I don't know which one to use).

This is the files I have in the original ROM firmware.

[image]

Please advise me how I can get back to my original Android or install any other Android OS, so that I can use this phone.

Thanks.

Comment: you can't flash ROM without modifying boot partition https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214902

Comment: GSI's requires treble ready device. in your case only lineageos devices specific release will work. flash the whole zip it contains a set of partitions https://android.stackexchange.com/q/213272