# OS Version relation between android and lineage OS

Tags: applications, lineageos

I have currently Android 6.0 Device but app which I am trying to install only supports Android 7.0+.
I am thinking of installing lineage OS.
Is there Lineage OS 7.0 etc. equivalent of Android 7.0, so that app can be installed or I need to stay with android.

Comment: @alecxs, this answers where I can find custom ROMs. I want to know what is relation between them. Means compatibility of apps. How their version relate. If app requires Android 7+ in play store, what it means for lineage os.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to get old LineageOS ROMs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213272/where-to-get-old-lineageos-roms)

Comment: 14 = android 7 (increase +1)

Comment: Ya that's what I was looking for, Thanks

Comment: https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/LineageOS#Version_history