# How to update Android version of old phone

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, twrp, lineageos, rom-update

I have an old tablet([Lenovo Phab 2](https://www.flipkart.com/lenovo-phab-2-gunmetal-gray-32-gb/p/itmep4bhwqtfmpdd?pid=MOBEZPVENHEVMQDZ&lid=LSTMOBEZPVENHEVMQDZISYRRI)) with Android 6. I need to upgrade the Android version to 7 or heigher to run some special app for my business. I checked TWRP and Lineage OS. There were some tutorials with the links. But those links are broken now. So I came to know that this is a common scenario to all who need to upgrade their old Android device. What is the generic solution for this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update Android on my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/how-do-i-update-android-on-my-device)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to get old LineageOS ROMs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213272/where-to-get-old-lineageos-roms)